# Can I suggest that a question be migrated to another stack exchange site?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, migration

I saw a question that belongs more to quantitative-finance.SE than to stats.SE.

1. Is there a way to migrate questions across SE sites?
2. If there isn't, is it appropriate to suggest the user ask on another forum?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure -- flag it for moderator attention. When you flag, in the mod comment indicate which site you think the question should go to.

If this is a common thing, we can "unlock" a migration path from one site to another so it shows up as one of up to 4 (+meta) default choices.

Comment: @ Jeff Atwood Currently it's possible to request a move to math, SO, and one other -- but not quant.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I think it is a good idea to add a path to quant.

Comment: @mbq we're a little hesitant to unlock paths to sites that are still in beta, though.

Answer (score 7):

1. Yes.  The best way is to flag the question (click on `flag` beneath the question and fill out the form).  This alerts the moderators and passes your suggestion or concern along to them.
2. Yes, but please do not suggest that people cross-post messages.  It is best to have them migrated.