# Flagging as off topic

Tags: discussion, closing-questions

I saw a question ([here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/70877/how-to-break-the-table-elements-in-latex)) that was clearly off-topic and could be (and probably has been) answered on tex.stackexchange.com. However, when I tried to flag it, was given the option of saying it was better suited for our meta site, the math Stack Exchange site, or SO. When none of these options are appropriate, there doesn't seem to be a way of either writing in another Stack Exchange site, or marking it as generally off-topic (see screenshot below). What do moderators prefer or expect users do in this situation? Downvote and/or comment without a flag? Or just leave it alone? Something else? Have I missed something?

[image]

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of [Can I suggest that a question be migrated to another stack exchange site?](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/q/884/930)

Comment: Re: *"or marking it as generally off-topic"* - In the closing options, you can close as off topic without specifying a different site for it to go to. The option is called 'Other' and it requires you to write a comment about why it's off topic. I'm not sure if this exists in the flagging box before you have the rep to close.

Comment: Thanks @Macro. I don't see that option, so it must not be available to lowly users! I think it would be nice if "Other" was one of the options in the box above. Ie, if the options were meta, math, so, or other.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem -- I can see the response box for sending it to tex.se.com just fine in your screenshot :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indeed, there are [pre-defined migration paths](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/505/930) (mostly because off-topic questions on this site are often of potential interest on SO or math.SE). I appreciate that users [**flag such questions**](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/884/930), so that moderators can handle the migration quickly. You can also leave a comment to the OP, but in this case don't forget to remind him or her not to cross-post.

Comment: Thanks. So in a case like this, we should use the general flag for moderator attention and describe that it should be migrated to another site rather than flag as off topic?

Comment: @smillig You can flag and leave a comment to suggest a better place. High-rep users are also part of the [moderation](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) process.

Comment: +1 especially for the point about not cross-posting.